Cookies are not immediately set when setting them in middleware, and reading them in page
In my real application, I am trying to see if the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, I will show them a LOGOUT button. If they are not logged in, I want to show them a LOGIN button.
But I am getting a problem, that the cookie first time is being undefined when reading it, although it exists, the second time, it is there.
I am trying to set a cookie in middleware.ts file, then I am trying to read it (for demo in this simple reproducible code) in one of the pages.
This is a Next.js 15 project with app router.
All with server components.
I am setting a cookie in middleware.ts, and I am making sure the cookie is always set and there. Then in a page, In a nested server component, I am trying to read that cookie once again. But I am getting undefined.
I open my browser, open dev tools, navigated to the cookies section, then, request localhost:3000, (my application). a cookie gets in, but in the page, the cookie value isn't printed, I am getting (cookie is undefined). This only happens the first time, but if you refresh the page, subsequent requests will see the cookie value and it works.
Look at the demo here:

Folder:
.
├── bun.lockb
├── next.config.ts
├── next-env.d.ts
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── cookie-block.tsx
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── functions
│   │   └── auth-cookie.ts
│   └── middleware.ts
└── tsconfig.json

src/middleware.ts:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { getAuthCookie, setAuthCookie } from './functions/auth-cookie'

export default async function middleware() {
  // # ensure cookie exists
  const authToken = await getAuthCookie()
  if (!authToken) await setAuthCookie()
  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/((?!_next/static|favicon.ico).*)',
}

src/functions/auth-cookie.ts:
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

const COOKIE_NAME = 'auth'

export const setAuthCookie = async () => {
  const cookieStore = await cookies()
  const hardcodedValue = 'abcd123'
  cookieStore.set(COOKIE_NAME, hardcodedValue, {})
}
export const getAuthCookie = async () => {
  const cookieStore = await cookies()
  const cookie = cookieStore.get(COOKIE_NAME)
  return cookie?.value
}

src/app/page.tsx:
import { CookieBlock } from './cookie-block'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-orange-400 flex justify-center h-screen w-screen items-center flex-col gap-y-16">
      <h1 className="font-extrabold text-4xl">This page is just for demo</h1>
      <CookieBlock />
    </div>
  )
}

src/app/cookie-block.tsx:
import { getAuthCookie } from '@/functions/auth-cookie'
export const CookieBlock = async () => {
  const authToken = await getAuthCookie()
  return (
    <div className="bg-orange-700 text-center rounded-xl p-5">
      <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold">Your cookie is:</h3>
      <h4>
        <i>{authToken ?? 'IT IS UNDEFINED'}</i>
      </h4>
    </div>
  )
}


 Github repo Click here

I can't find explicit documentation for this, but it sounds like the cookie store's get method is only looking at cookies from the request. If you set a cookie to be returned with the response, and then try to get that cookie as part of the same request, it won't be found.
